# QEMU: How to obtain host address from Ubuntu guest?

Tags: ip, qemu, hosts, address

When using UTM on a Mac with a Ubuntu guest in it, I need to obtain the host IP address (of my Mac) from the guest to mount its file system by sshfs (or any other mount).
It runs UTM based on QEMU.
I searched the internet on it, but only found the other way around: the guest IP address which is easy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could write the IP address of the host into a file & mount the file onto guest os?

Comment: Why not use the hostname instead of the IP?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of options here::

1. Write the IP address of the host into a file & mount the file onto guest OS
2. Install hypervisor-specific RPMs on guest VM like `vmtoolsd` for VMware, `hypervkvpd` for HyperV, etc., With these packages, you could fetch a few required attributes from a host like a hostname, IP address, etc.,

Comment: Indeed using a hostname like `hostname.local` works, as this is always visible within the same network, as long I use 'bridged network' in UTM / QEMU or VirtualBox (the latter on an Intel Mac).